# Regular expression for $\{x : \#_{01}(x) \mod 3 = 0\}$

Tags: regular-expressions

Let $L_1$ be the language over alphabet $\{0, 1\}$ defined by $L_1 = \{x : \#_{01}(x) \mod 3 = 0\}$.

Give a regular expression that denotes $L_1$, and justify its correctness

---

## Attempt

Believe this is asking for number of $01$'s in $x$ but $|x|$ must be an even number. Like $x = 0101$, $|x| = |0101| = 4 \mod 3 = 1$ wouldn't work. However $x = 010101, |x| = 6$ would work?

How would I make a regex for this?

$R_1 = (01)^*$. How would I do the mod condition?

Comment: Would $010011001$ also be in $L_1$ since the number of $01$s is 3?

Comment: Actually yeah that makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that any amount of ones at the start or zeroes at the end has no influence on the number of $01$ pairs. Then in the middle you want any multiple of three of $01$ pairs, giving:

$$1^*(0^+1^+0^+1^+0^+1^+)^*0^*$$

Comment: what is the $0^+$ operator mean?

Comment: @TreeGaren One or more zeroes. You could also write $00^*$.

Comment: Would strings like 100111010001 work for this?

Comment: @TreeGaren Yes.